# How do the tags which show up on a user's profile, get chosen?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

I couldn't find a correlation with questions I've answered or marked as favorite.  Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you answer a question with the tags "Dog", "Cat" and "Beaver" and you get at least +1 on your answer, your profile will then show "Dog", "Cat", and "Beaver" for your tags.

If you ask a question with the tags "Dog", "Cat", and "Beaver" and you get at least +1 on your question, your profile will be updated to show "Dog x2", "Cat x2" and "Beaver x2"

The pattern continues as you continue to answer questions and ask your own questions with the variety of tags out there. The more answers and questions you have for a specific tag, the higher the number will climb.

Comment: My original answer had the "and you get at least 1 upvote" part, but looking at his profile he has python 2x but only one of his two python answers got an upvote. Maybe he got a downvote in the other one?

Comment: Perhaps. I was unaware of the "at least +1" until you said it. So if I'm wrong, I'm blaming you

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you answer a question the cardinality of all the tags in that question get +1'ed on your profile. I am not sure if that same happens with questions you ask, though. So in your SO profile you have python 2x, because 2 of your answers were on questions tagged python, and so on.

Comment: I'm almost sure it counts questions as well.

Comment: I am sure it does not include questions asked. I have asked a question in the "towers-of-hanoi" tag on SO, but it does not show up on my profile.